# Is it possible to have a lookup that get datas from multiple table?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

In Dynamics Ax I can use `sysTableLookup` to show a combo lookup with a grid with multiple columns?

How to get data from multiple table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join to other tables in your query, see below example from [Axaptapedia](http://www.axaptapedia.com/index.php?title=SysTableLookup_class)

```
public void lookup()
{
  Query                   query = new Query();
  QueryBuildDataSource    dsCustTable;
  QueryBuildDataSource    dsCustTrans;

  // Instantiate sysTableLookup object using table which will provide the visible fields 
  SysTableLookup  sysTableLookup = sysTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(CustTable), this);
  ;

  // Create the query.  Only select customers where blocked != All and one more more transactions
  // exist with no closed date
  dsCustTable = query.addDataSource(tableNum(CustTable));
  dsCustTable.addRange(fieldNum(CustTable, Blocked)).value(queryNotValue(CustVendorBlocked::All));

  dsCustTrans = dsCustTable.addDataSource(tableNum(CustTrans));
  dsCustTrans.relations(true);
  dsCustTrans.joinMode(JoinMode::ExistsJoin);
  dsCustTrans.addRange(fieldNum(CustTrans, Closed)).value(queryValue(dateNull()));

  // Set the query to be used by the lookup form
  sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);

  // Specify the fields to show in the form.  In this case we have chosen
  // Account number, name, and dimension one.
  sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(CustTable, AccountNum));
  sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldId2Ext(fieldNum(CustTable, Dimension), 1));

  // Perform the lookup
  sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();
}
```

Comment: This lookup will only show fields from CustTable, one single table, and not from multiple tables.

Comment: CustTable & CustTrans, what have I missed here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use display methods in your lookup pulling data from other tables.

Or you can use this extension:
http://kashperuk.blogspot.co.uk/2008/09/sysmultitableloookup-dynamic-lookups.html